# javascript to change an elements class based on days of the week

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

I want to call a different css class based on days of the week.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function () {
       var d = new Date();
       var weekday = new Array(7);
       weekday[0] = "Sunday";
       weekday[1] = "Monday";
       weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
       weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
       weekday[4] = "Thursday";
       weekday[5] = "Friday";
       weekday[6] = "Saturday";
       var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
       if (n =='Tuesday') {
           document.getElementById("td").className = "MyClass";
       } else {
           document.getElementById("td").className = "red";
       }
    }
</script>
```

But this code is not working. Someone please help.
This is my full code

```
<style>

.red {
    background-color: #ff0000;
     }
.blue {
    background-color: #0000ff;
      }
.MyClass {
        background-color: #b65d36;
    }
</style>`
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<DIV color id="loading" align="center" style="border: 1px                solid #008080; position: fixed; top: 48%; left: 40%;">
<b>Product Service</b> <br /> 
<I>Loading, Please Wait....</I>
<br><img src="../Images/progressbar.gif" alt="" style="border- style:      none; border-width: 0px" /></DIV>');
window.onload = function () {
 document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
 var d = new Date();
 var weekday = new Array(7);
 weekday[0] = "Sunday";
       weekday[1] = "Monday";
       weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
       weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
       weekday[4] = "Thursday";
       weekday[5] = "Friday";
       weekday[6] = "Saturday";
       var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
       if (n =='Tuesday') {
           document.getElementById("td").className = "MyClass";
       } else {
           document.getElementById("td").className = "red";
       }
   }
</script>
<link href="../Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head><body>
<form id="form2" runat="server">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>`       `  
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" >
<ProgressTemplate>
<div class="modal">
<div class="center">
<img alt="" src="../Images/progressbar.gif" />
</div>
</div>
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<div align="center" id="div_First" style="width: 100%;margin:auto;">
<table cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Lato;" cellpadding="0" width="98%"   border="0">
<tr>
<td align="left" colspan="2" class="Header" valign="middle"><b>Report</b>   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="padding-left:0px;">
<table width="100%"  style="border: 1px solid #669999;background-color:#FFFF95; color:black;">
<tr>
<td width="33%"  align="left" valign="top" >
<table  width="100%" >
<tr>  <td >Product </td>         
<td align="left">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Product" TabIndex="1"  CssClass="txtboxAll"   Width="210px" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>                                    
<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown5" runat="server" 
Category="Product" TargetControlID="ddl_Product" 
PromptText="[Select  Product]" LoadingText="Loading Product..." 
ServicePath="~/Services/Productservice.asmx"
ServiceMethod="GetDropDownProduct" Enabled="True">
</asp:CascadingDropDown>    
</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td >Name</td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_name" CssClass="txtboxAll" AutoPostBack="true"   Width="210px" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdd_facility" runat="server" Category="name"   TargetControlID="ddl_name" PromptText="[Select Name]" LoadingText="Loading Name..."      ServicePath="~/Services/Productservice.asmx"  ServiceMethod="GetDropDownname">
 </asp:CascadingDropDown> 
  </td>      
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td align="right" colspan="3">
  <asp:Button ID="but_submit" runat="server" CssClass="btn5" Text="Search"/>   </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

This is my full code. It's not working. The CSS class `MyClass` is not working.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: What is the error if any?

Comment: Your code is proper..... please show us more code.... if possible make a fiddle for the same

Comment: Just taking a wild guess here. You may intend to use `getElementByTagName`  instead of `getElementById` here.

Answer (score 0):

When I open the console on your code I see the following:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null"

This line appears to be the problem:

```
       document.getElementById("td").className = "MyClass";
```

Nothing with an id of "td" exists in your page (hence the preivous error). I believe you want something like this:

```
   if (n =='Tuesday') {
        var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
            arr[i].className = "MyClass";
   } else {
        var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
            arr[i].className = "red";
   }
```

Otherwise, create a tag with an id of "td"